# Error message when running cell in vscode interactive

Tags: python-3.x

I get the following error when running a code cell in my Python file to vscode interactive: : "Missing viewType for 'vscode-interactive:/Interactive-1.interactive'"

Has anyone gotten this before and knows how to solve it?

Br
Haakon

Tried to change virtenv

Comment: where is the code ?  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi! It is independent of the code in the cell. No code will run in the interactive window because of the error message.
PS: It works now. Solved without me doing anything than re-opening the program over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is an issue related to a hanging code instance. A restart or closing code and killing all operations should also work.